# Indentations in If-Else?

Tags: java

I am a beginner at Java and this code example came up in class:

```
int horsepower = 15;
      if(horsepower > 15)
         if(horsepower <= 20)
            System.out.println("There is a lot of horsepower");
      else
          System.out.println("The car super fast");
```

the output is nothing but I can't understand why.

I have 2 questions I would like to clarify:

1. why did the code under the else statement not get executed?
2. I understand that without the brackets { }, the if condition can only execute the next statement. In this case, if horsepower variable is 17 instead, will "There is a lot of horsepower." be printed ? I am unsure if the System.out.println("There is a lot of horsepower"); still qualifies as being part of the next statement of the first if condition.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: (Basically, because Java is not Python and any (non-empty/zero) amount of white-space equivalent: The `else` "belongs to" the 2nd `if`.)

Answer (score 3):

Indentation has absolutely no syntactic or semantic meaning in Java, and indeed in most popular languages (the main exception is Python).

Which *if* does your *else* belong to? This is an instance of the famous [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.
The syntax of Java associates each *else* to the innermost *if*, so the Java compiler understands your code in a way which is different than what your indentation suggests. If you want to associate the *else* with the outer *if*, you can use curly brackets.